# How to apply changes in bootstrap.min.css file

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am building a WordPress website and I am using bootswatch theme. This is driving me insane right now, what I want to do is to set my navbar burger menu to show on `1100px` not on `992px` as it is set in the `bootstrap.min.css` file. The insane part is that when I change the `@media` property in style editor (dev console) it works, when I change it in the actual file it still shows `992px`. For that matter, any change I make in the actual file is not being applied. I tried clearing the cache and all that stuff but no luck. Is there something I am missing to change a simple property value?

Comment: Override the style in your OWN css file and not in the bootstrap file (you may use `!important` to override the style or import your  style sheet after the bootstrap files)

Comment: Or add special class to your wanted DOM and add style with the special class in your style sheet

Comment: Well what I did now is changed from ```expand-lg``` to ```expand-xl``` in my class so it is showing at ```1200px```. Still bugging the hell out of me why I cannot sucessfully  edit .min.css or .css. Tried to unminify then change then minify again, all of that nothing works :/. The problem is not in overriding the value , now I want to know why I can't change it directly

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the bootstrap styles by simply defining styles in your own CSS file by giving an extra custom class to your container. First, you have to create your own CSS file and import that file properly in your HTML, then give a custom class to your container and define the width in your own CSS file. Here is a little code snippet that may help you:

### HTML code

```
<div class='container custom-class'>//your container goes here</div>
```

### CSS code

```
.custom-class{
width: 1100px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change in bootstrap file then do not edit in minified version first make changes in unminified version if it works. Then minify your updated file and use that file because it is not recommended to make changes in minified files.

Comment: Not working, tried it. Still the same result

Comment: Have you tried this @ahmed-ali Solution? Override your element style with !impotent keyword?

Comment: Check out my comment below the question

Answer (score 0):

From the Bootstrap documentation it looks like they define the breakpoints in the scss file:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#between-breakpoints

Has this been replaced by something from Bootswatch? I would guess that bootswatch is still using the scss from Bootstrap, you may need to change it in that file also (_variables.scss)